# Firebase hosting redirects www.example.com to example.com

Tags: web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have completed my site setup via Firebase hosting, and everything works correctly.
The problem is that my site make a redirect from `www.example.com` to `example.com`

How can I prevent it? How can I get always `www.example.com/`?

This is my `firebase.json` :

```
"hosting": {
"public": "files",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*"
],
"headers": [ {
  "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Cache-Control",
    "value" : "max-age=7200"
  }]
  }],
"cleanUrls": true }
```

Comment: Connect `www.example.com` to the Firebase hosting after which it'll automatically ask you if you want to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `example.com` registered as the domain in your [Firebase Hosting console](https://firebase.corp.google.com/project/firebase-kato-sandbox/hosting/main). Thus, the domain point there.

Register that domain as `www.example.com` and it will always show as this. Note that your `TXT` records still go on the apex (i.e. `example.com`) and you can leave your DNS configuration as-is, assuming both `www` and the apex already properly point to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: does that make any difference if you register www.example.com and redirect example.com to www.example.com ?